# Drupal 7 - add HTML inside #link form type entry?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I need to add HTML markup to the `#title` field of a Drupal 7 `#type` link form element. The output should look roughly like this:

```html
<a href="/saveprogress/nojs/123" id="saveprogress-link" class="ajax-processed">
  <span data-icon="&#61515;" aria-hidden="true" class="mymodule_symbol"></span>
  Save Progress
</a>
```

Since I'm doing some ajax forms, I can't just use `#markup` and `l()` function. Here's an example without the span:

```php
function mymodule_save_progress_link($nid) {
  return array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => t('Save Progress'),
    '#href' => 'saveprogress/nojs/' . $nid,
    '#id' => 'saveprogress-link',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'wrapper' => 'level-form',
      'method' => 'html',
    ),
  );
}

function mymodule_print_links($nid=NULL) {
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_modal_add_js();

  $build['saveprogress_link'] = mymodule_save_progress_link($nid);

  return '<div id="level-form">' . drupal_render($build) . '</div>';
}
```

When I add the `<span>` to the `#title` field, it's escaped and not interpreted as HTML. How can I insert this span (or other markup) to the tile field of a `link` type form element. This form element is not well documented on the Drupal  site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's actually a much simpler way than custom-rolling a theme - just tell `drupal_render()` to treat `'#title'` as html.

```
function mymodule_save_progress_link($nid) {
  return array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => '<span>unescaped HTML here</span> '.t('Save Progress'),
    '#href' => 'saveprogress/nojs/' . $nid,
    '#id' => 'saveprogress-link',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'wrapper' => 'level-form',
      'method' => 'html',
    ),
    '#options' => array(
      'html' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

This could be very handy for adding images or other elements to a click-able area.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way, but here's one working method by using a custom theme. You need to register the custom theme function in hook_theme(), then disable and re-enable you module to update the theme registry. In your custom theme function, you can rewrite the output HTML, but you'll need to add a different class, 'use-ajax'.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array (
    'mymodule_link' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
    ),
  );
}

/**
* Returns HTML for a mymodule link
*
* @param $variables
*   An associative array containing:
*   - element: A render element containing the properties of the link.
*
* @ingroup themeable
*/
function theme_mymodule_link($variables) {
  return l(
    '<span data-icon="&#61515;" '.
      'aria-hidden="true" class="mymodule-symbol"></span> '.
      $variables['element']['#title'],
    $variables['element']['#href'],
    array(
     'html' => TRUE, 
     'attributes' => array(
       'class' => array('use-ajax'), 
       'title' => $variables['element']['#title']
     )
    )
  );
}
```

Finally, require the form element to use this theme:

```
function mymodule_save_progress_link($nid) {
  return array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => t('Save Progress'),
    '#href' => 'saveprogress/nojs/' . $nid,
    '#id' => 'saveprogress-link',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'wrapper' => 'level-form',
      'method' => 'html',
    ),
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_link',
  );
}
```